# Doctrine Inheritance and MySQL Join Table Limit

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with 61 join table limit of mysql. I have 57+ different classes extending Base Class which contain association to comments, likes, tags. And MySQL is crashing when i get most commented. Doctrine has to join whole discriminator maps and comments itself and order by COUNT(comments).

Is there way to fix that ?

And is there another way to achieve comments for different types of entities without inheritance and copying same association all over again?

Here is sample schema of Entities. When I want to add new Entity Type with comments,likes I just extends BaseClass to receive these features.

[image]

Comment: Just a question, are you using Doctrine cache ?

Comment: Yes, but what helps me this?

Comment: Hm... It's not a good answer but there are only two things you can do: `1) Reduce the complexity of your queries`, `2) Use the entities only when REALLY needed`, `3) Increase your MySQL limits`

Comment: As i don't know what is the structure of your database nor what _exactly_ you're trying to achieve, i can't give a good answer.

Comment: Also, if each `category` of your blog has it's own table, then there is the problem. You _shouldn't_ do something like that

Comment: @jgabriel I believe you cannot increase join table limit of mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/joins-limits.html

Comment: @jgabriel You have different types of objects. Article, Poll, Post and etc and etc, for every type you want to have comments. The only way of implement that is base table and inheritance mapping, and base class is holding all the comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45060/discussion-between-cappy-and-jgabriel)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do is have many different entity types which can be commented on.

First thing to do would be to step back from Doctrine and thing about the simplest table structure you would need to accomplish this.

Something like this may suffice:

Comments

```
 _______________________
| id | type | entity_id |
 ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

It is nice in Doctrine to have bi-directional relationships in your base class for convenience but sometimes they are not the best choice. Maybe it would simplify your architecture to perform a query directly on the comments table by entity type and id.

You may also want to consider removing the Base class and having each entity be standalone.

Since a blog post can exist in a context where it does not have comments (on a blog that doesn't allow commenting for example) then `$blog->getComments()` wouldn't make much sense.

Making this change you could do something like this instead:

```
$comments = $commentsRepository->findCommentsForEntity($entity);
$commentsCount = count($comments);
```

and the repository could generate the needed query passing the entity as the `entity_id` parameter and setting the required comment type based on the entity type.

Comment: Yes, that is also solution but that way I loose advantage of Relational Relational DBs and Foreign Keys. If application logic is not working properly there will be un-needed records in DB. Everything get much complex, If I delete entity I have to delete all his comments and other stuffs.

Comment: Typically the deletion of an entity should be done in only 1 place in your application. In this case you simply add the deletion of that entity's related comments. The database mainly just holds the data it should be the applications job to manage it correctly.

Also having some left over data in the database should never be problematic. You can always create clean-up scripts that can be run if the application was not functioning properly and left some things behind.

Comment: Yes, this also can be done with Event Listener for deletion, but I still don't right it's the right way. I want to reserve FKs in order to keep data integrity.